# Magento2 Get Payment Method API Returns Empty

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, rest-api

When i trying get The Payment Methods using REST API , "rest/V1/carts/{cartId}/payment-methods" , it is returning Empty Array as a result.

I'm passing Admin Bearer Token as Authorization.

Comment: This WEB API endpoint returns only active payment methods (enabled in admin panel) and available for the specified quote. The payment method implements `\Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface::isAvailable` it should return `true`, also payment method should satisfy default validators like `useOnCheckout`, `useForCountry`, `useForCurrency`, `orderTotalMinMax` - some of them can be configured via Admin Panel, some in `config.xml` for per a payment integration.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar issue as of now.
with guest-carta api.

```
https://www.example.com/rest/{store}/V1/guest- 
carts/{quote_mask_id}/payment-information
```

What I did is I build a wrapper api of my own and called this api to initate order and then in case if the api response is empty I am calling sql query i.e

```
SELECT * FROM `quote_id_mask` WHERE `masked_id` = 
'{QUOTE_KEY}'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `quote_id_mask` WHERE `quote_id` = 
'{QUOTE_ID_MASK}'
```

It will give you entityID to initiate order for payment processing.